# React Native Login Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, native

My Login form works fine, except for one annoying detail. Although it verifies the email and password correctly, it does not update the screen correctly. I have to click the Login button twice. I want that it jumps to the "Principal" page. I think it's something to do with the life cycle of the component that affects the rendering. Any idea what the problem is?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Principal from './Principal';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

function Alerta(data) {
  Alert.alert(data.correo);
}

function UserLoginFunction(data) {
  fetch('http://localhost/app/login.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: data.correo,
      password: data.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      if (responseJson === 'CORRECT') {
        global.isLogged = true;
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.forceUpdate();
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Invalid login or password: try again");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

export default function Login() {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => UserLoginFunction(data);

  if (global.isLogged === true) {
    return <Principal />;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex:1, padding: 30, paddingTop: 40 }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.avatar}
            source={require('./assets/login-bottom.png')}
          />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#f5f6fa', width: 220 }}>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>E-mail address:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="E-mail address:"
                autoCapitalize="none"                
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
              />
            )}
            name="correo"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.correo && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide an email address</Text>
          )}
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Password:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password:"
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
                secureTextEntry={true}
              />
            )}
            name="password"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide a password</Text>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Log in</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

UPDATE: I tried this and it doesn't work either!

```
function UserLoginFunction(data) {
  fetch('http://localhost/app/login.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: data.correo,
      password: data.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      if (responseJson === 'CORRECT') {
        global.isLogged = true;
        return true;
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Invalid login or password: try again");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    return false;
}

export default function Login() {
  
  const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => setLogged(UserLoginFunction(data));

  if (this.isLogged === true) {
    return <Principal />;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex:1, padding: 30, paddingTop: 40 }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.avatar}
            source={require('./assets/login-bottom.png')}
          />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#f5f6fa', width: 220 }}>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>E-mail address:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="E-mail address:"
                autoCapitalize="none"                
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
              />
            )}
            name="correo"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.correo && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide an email address</Text>
          )}
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Password:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password:"
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
                secureTextEntry={true}
              />
            )}
            name="password"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide a password</Text>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Log in</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is `this.forceUpdate()` and why is it being called twice?

Comment: Why not, use state to store the value of `isLogged` so that it rerenders automatically when `isLogged` changes

Comment: I used `this.forceUpdate()` twice in a clumsy attempt to render, and it didn't work.

Comment: Great! I think it's an excellent idea to use the state to store the value of `isLogged`. I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `useState()` hook for isLogged, so that when `isLogged== false`, you can access only Login Screen, otherwise you can access pages inside your app. 
 `const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState<boolean>(false);`
` if (responseJson === 'CORRECT') {setIsLogged(true)} `

Comment: Thank you Ani! I have found the solution. I declared `UserLoginFunction` inside `Login` to have access to the status variable, and be able to use `setLogged(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ani!

I have found the solution. I declared UserLoginFunction inside Login to have access to the status variable, and be able to use setLogged(true).

```
export default function Login() {
  
  const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => UserLoginFunction(data);

  if (isLogged === true) {
    return <Principal />;
  }

function UserLoginFunction(data) {
  fetch('http://localhost/app/login.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: data.correo,
      password: data.password,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      if (responseJson === 'CORRECT') {
          setLogged(true);
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Invalid login or password: try again");
      }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex:1, padding: 30, paddingTop: 40 }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.avatar}
            source={require('./assets/login-bottom.png')}
          />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#f5f6fa', width: 220 }}>
        <View style={styles.form}>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>E-mail address:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="E-mail address:"
                autoCapitalize="none"                
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
              />
            )}
            name="correo"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.correo && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide an email address</Text>
          )}
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Password:</Text>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
              <TextInput
                placeholder="Password:"
                style={styles.input}
                onBlur={onBlur}
                onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
                value={value}
                secureTextEntry={true}
              />
            )}
            name="password"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            defaultValue=""
          />
          {errors.password && (
            <Text style={styles.error}>You must provide a password</Text>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Log in</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```